# How to use Toolbar and ScrollView?

Tags: android

How to use toolbar and ScrollView?

I have code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:background="#000000"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But this is not showing EditText. What should I correct?

I don't have to use LinearLayout - this I can change. I have to use only ScrollView and toolbar, but these are my attempts.

Comment: use `FrameLayout` instead of the outermost `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Change orientation of `LinearLayout` from `horizontal` to `vertical`:
`android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Still I don't see EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I’d use either:

A Relative Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp" />

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/scrollable_content_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        tools:text="hello world" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

or a ConstraintLayout (I’d prefer this one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/scrollable_content_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        tools:text="hello world" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now you can see it:

[image: Preview]